# How can travails be romantic?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The best ‘classic’ novels are an odd mixture. On the one hand, they tend to be
> written by people with strange names and are set in increasingly distant and
> peculiar ages, where the clothes are never dry-cleaned and the characters fight
> duels, go to balls, ride horses and take snuff. But they also pull off the miraculous
> feat of speaking to us more directly, more urgently than anything written in our
> own time. While seemingly engaged in her own love story in nineteenth-century
> rural France, Emma Bovary will continue to shed light on the **[romantic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/romantic) [travails](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/travail)** of
> people living in twenty-first-century space stations.

Isn't this an oxymoron? How do you determine/deduce which definition of **romantic** applies? Following user Dan Bron's comment, how would Definitions 2 and 3 fit?

> 2. Of, characterized by, or suggestive of an idealized view of reality:
>
> 3. Relating to or denoting the movement of romanticism:

Comment: You're asking how romance can be a *painful or laborious effort*?  Whew, where do I begin....

Comment: I think the definition of _romantic_ you rare looking for is more along the lines of _having to do with intimate relationships_. And the _travails_ are the _painful or laborious efforts_ that Dan Bron mentioned. To repeat his question: do you have a problem envisaging that amorous relationships can involve such efforts? Because, if you do, I think reading the book itself (instead of an article _about_ the book) might explain it very nicely.

Comment: Emma Bovary's husband bored her to tears. She yearned for excitement. Her idea of love was that it must always be exciting and never mundane. That is a "romantic" view of love. When "manning" their space stations, NASA will probably look for women who are not the Emma Bovary type, even though life on a space station can hardly be said to be *mundane*.

Answer (score 1):

It's the first definition of "romantic" that applies, though - "Conducive to or characterized by the expression of love." The clue that the "love" definition is the correct one is right there in the sentence: "While seemingly engaged in her own **love story**."

The second and third definitions do not apply here.

Comment: Thanks. How do you determine that the 2nd and 3rd definitions don't apply?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @LePressentiment, I'm not sure what more you would want beyond what is already in the answer ("the clue... is right there in the sentence: "... **love story**").